# Exact sequences of $SU(N)$ and $SO(N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, exact-sequence

We know that the spin group $Spin(N)$ has a short exact sequence of Lie groups

$$1 \to Z_2 \to Spin(N) \to SO(N) \to 1\textrm{.}$$

I wonder whether there are some examples for $SU(N)$ and $SO(N)$ groups

such that there exists an exact sequence as

> Q1. $$1 \to ? \to SU(N) \to ? \to 1$$

-

> Q2. $$1 \to ? \to SO(N) \to ? \to 1$$

Here I am interested to know the case where the question marks are nontrivial non-Abelian Lie groups.

In particular, I am interested to know when

$SU(N)$ is $SU(4)$ and $SU(5)$

and when

$SO(N)$ is $SO(8)$, $SO(9)$, and $SO(10)$.

Reference is very welcome. Thank you. :-)

Comment: for SO(N)=SO(32) will also be interesting.

Comment: I think there are essentially no examples of the form you want. For $\text{Spin}(4)$ there is an exceptional isomorphism $\text{Spin}(4) \cong \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2)$ but that's about it. The point is that essentially all of the corresponding Lie algebras are simple. (There are examples if you allow the first group to be discrete as in the case of spin groups.)

Comment: It's not what you're looking for, but there are fibrations $SU(n-1) \to SU(n) \to S^{2n-1}$ and $SO(n-1) \to SO(n) \to S^{n-1}$ coming from the actions of $SU(n)$ on $S^{2n-1}\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $SO(n)$ on $S^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if that helps. Are you interested in the sequences for their own sake, or do you have something specific in mind (e.g., computing homotopy groups)?

Comment: Also interesting, but not an answer to your question, is the fiber sequence for the lagrangian grassmannian, $SO(n) \rightarrow SU(n) \rightarrow S\Lambda(n)$ see page 2 http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/arnold3.pdf