# Exact sequences of $1 \to A \to SU(N) \to B \to 1$, special unitary group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, exact-sequence

Inspired by the [nice post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846512/exact-sequences-of-sun-and-son), I am particularly looking into the exact sequences of SU(N), but I will like to loosen the conditions of the previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846512/exact-sequences-of-sun-and-son),

> Q1. $$1 \to A \to SU(N) \to B \to 1$$

where any of $A$,$B$ can contain finite group or discrete groups.

---

I am particularly interested in SU(5),

> Q2. $$1 \to A \to SU(5) \to B \to 1$$

I wonder whether there is any example such that both $A$ and $B$ contains the same number of generators of continuous part of Lie groups (there can be an additional discrete finite group parts such as additional $\mathbb{Z_N}$)? (for example $SU(5)$ has 24 generators. Is there any example such that $A$ and $B$ have 12 generators for continuous part of Lie groups for each $A$, $B$.) How about 
$$A=U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)\;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\;A \supset U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)?$$

Or whether there is any example such that $B$ 
$$B=U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)\;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\;B \supseteq U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)?$$
(there can be an additional discrete finite group parts for $B$ such as additional $\mathbb{Z_N}$.)

Comment: Isn't $SU(N)$ simple save for a finite center? So unless $A$ is finite, $B$ is not going to be a group.

Comment: Jyrki is right. $A$ can be any subgroup of the center $\mathbb{Z}_N$. The largest possibility is $1 \to \mathbb{Z}_N \to \text{SU}(N) \to \text{PSU}(N) \to 1$.

Comment: You mean the largest $A$ can only be $Z_N$?