# Exact sequences of $1 \to A \to SO(N) \to B \to 1$, special orthogonal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, exact-sequence

Inspired by the [nice post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846512/exact-sequences-of-sun-and-son) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846718/exact-sequences-of-1-to-a-to-sun-to-b-to-1?noredirect=1#comment1746157_846718), apart from SU(N), now I am particularly looking into the exact sequences of SO(N), but I will like to loosen the conditions of the previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846512/exact-sequences-of-sun-and-son),

> Q1. $$1 \to A \to SO(N) \to B \to 1$$

where any of $A$,$B$ can contain finite group or discrete groups.

I am further interested in just **three cases SO(8), SO(9), SO(10)**,

-

> Q2. $$1 \to A \to SO(n) \to B \to 1$$ 
>   I wonder whether, when there is any example such that $A$ 
>   $$A=U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)\;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\;A \supseteq U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)?$$
>   (there can be an additional discrete finite group parts for $A$ such as additional $\mathbb{Z_N}$)
>   or whether there is any example such that $B$ 
>   $$B=U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)\;\;\; \text{or} \;\;\;B \supseteq U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)?$$
>   (there can be an additional discrete finite group parts for $B$ such as additional $\mathbb{Z_N}$)

Comment: You seem to have posted the exact same question twice...I am presuming the other one is the "proper" version?

Comment: Dear all, I thought the previous one is mainly for SU(5). Now this one is for SO(8), SO(9), SO(10)... These two questions are different, they are different even in the level of titles.

Comment: Although, on re-reading, they are different, I don't understand what you mean about the titles? They have the same title...

Comment: @user1729: Well, your son might be your sun; but my sun is not my son. :-)

Comment: @Asaf Ah, gotcha!